# Есть ли возможность открыть "Средства разработчика" в WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

В стандартных методах не нашел, только отобразить HTML документа.
Но может есть возможность как-то открыть "Средства разработчика", которые в IE вызываются по F12?

Comment: А в контекстном меню там нет Inspect Element?

Comment: Нет, такого нет. Есть только стандартные - "Просмотреть HTML", "Копировать", "Вставить" и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такой возможности нет. Все же `WebBrowser` -- это не Internet Explorer.

Если вам нужно отслеживать ошибки, это можно сделать так:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) =>
{
    webBrowser.Document.Window.Error += (w, we) =>
    {
        we.Handled = true;

        // реагируем на ошибку
        Debug.WriteLine(
            string.Format(
               "Error: {1}\nline: {0}\nURL: {2}",
               we.LineNumber,
               we.Description,
               we.Url));
    };
};
```

Если нужно получить тэг по клику, то это можно сделать, подписавшись на события нажатия кнопки мыши. Затем вызвать следующий код, передав ему координаты.

```
private static String GetTagNameByClick(WebBrowser webBrowser, Int32 x, Int32 y)
{
    Point point = webBrowser.PointToClient(new Point(x, y));

    HtmlElement element = webBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(point);

    return element.TagName;
}
```

Comment: Да мне не ошибки нужны, а удобное исследование dom-дерева. Ну, если нельзя, значит нельзя. :)

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко тогда только брать `DocumentText` и превращать его в дерево. Разбор писать самому или посмотреть библиотеки.